# Error working with PIP, no such file or directory after python update

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi

I just installed the latest python version on my raspberry pi and `python -V/python3 -V` shows 3.11.3.
Now when I check pip -V, it states: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory`
I guess the issue is that I installed pip with APT which installed it in `usr/bin` not `usr/local/bin`. What would be the best way forward?

`Which pip` gives `/usr/bin/pip`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip pip` gives `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'pip': File exists`
Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance :)